# How to differentiate domains from longer URLs in PHP?

Tags: php, url, dns, parse-url

I receive URLs from a PHP form with the `_POST` method.

I am sure they are URLs because jquery validate plugin tests them before sending.

Then I process them in PHP.

However, I want to make sure that :

`domain.com`
or
`domain.com/`

end with a `/`.

But, I want to make sure that :

`domain.com/page`
or
`domain.com/page/`
or
`domain.com/dir/page/`
or
`domain.com/page.html`

end without a `/`.

I found : [PHP: how to add trailing slash to absolute URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448176/php-how-to-add-trailing-slash-to-absolute-url) which was quite helpful.

I now use :

```
$rawarrival = $_POST["arrival"];

$url = parse_url($rawarrival);

if(!isset($url['path'])) $url['path'] = '/';
$arrival = $url['scheme']."://".$url['host'].$url['path'];
```

Nevertheless, I still can't make it to get a long URL (longer than just the domain) without a "/".

How should I twist that to make it work ?

Thank you.

Comment: You are never sure the input parameters are valid until you don't check them on the server-side.
It's simply possible to edit or disable javascript validating or just send custom request from another program. Always remember, that you must validate input parameters on server-side, too.

Comment: Alright people.

It seems like I got the answer from another forum :

http://www.siteduzero.com/forum/sujet/differencier-des-urls-longues-et-domaines-en-php

    $url = parse_url($rawarrival);
    $url['path'] = (isset($url['path']) && $url['path'] != '/')  ? rtrim($url['path'], '/') : '/';
    $arrival = $url['scheme']."://".$url['host'].$url['path'];

It works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: Ok jjurm. Thanks for the advice. I am not a dev. This is going to be only an internal tool and there is not much to hack... but sure.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the last character?

```
if (substr($url["path"], -1, 1) === "/") {
    $url["path"] = substr($url["path"], 0, -1);
}
```

(untested)

Comment: you can use `substr($url["path"], -1)`

Comment: Ok. I prefer to keep that one : $url = parse_url($rawarrival); $url['path'] = (isset($url['path']) && $url['path'] != '/') ? rtrim($url['path'], '/') : '/'; $arrival = $url['scheme']."://".$url['host'].$url['path'];